# Undefined class name 'MaterialApp' in Flutter. How to solve this issue?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created a flutter project using

`flutter create first`

after i go the codes using vs code and the error shows up saying

> undefined class name 'MaterialApp'

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you imported the `material.dart` class? Please share your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the Flutter SDK and the Dart versions. Finally upgraded the flutter sdk and that did the trick. This was suggested here [GitHub solution](https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/issues/133).
Try running the below command in the terminal inside Android Studio

```
flutter upgrade --force
```